# hooked and double-headed arrow in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

In `tikz-cd`, I would like to combine `hookleftarrow` and `two heads`.  It works just fine to write `\arrow[hook, two heads]{r}`, but if this arrow runs leftwards instead (with `{l}` instead of `{r}`) then the hook goes downwards instead of upwards, and `\arrow[hookleftarrow, two heads]{r}` just gives something like `$<--->>$`.  So I would also be happy with a way of either reflecting an arrow or rotating it by 180 degrees.

Comment: this probably doesn't belong here, but i also don't feel like making a question for it. why do "two heads" and "->>" look different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this acceptable? I used `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` to use syntax from arrows library to construct the left-ward double hook manually.

I also included the normal rightward hook for reference.

[image: left double hook]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzcd}
         A \arrow[cm double to - cm left hook]{r} & B
        \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[hook, two heads]{r} & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great!  Thanks a bunch -- and thanks for cleaning up the question too  :o)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `hook'`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A & B \arrow[l,hook,two heads] \arrow[r,hook] & C \\
A & B \arrow[l,hook',two heads] \arrow[r,hook,two heads] & C \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wasn't the OP also looking for double header?

Comment: @daleif Yes, fixed!